# Treeview para mostrar directorios vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Estoy mostrando un directorio en un treeview pero solo me muestra la carpeta principal como nodo y se puede expandir pero los subdirectorios no me los muestra como nodos si no como una sola lista aunque dentro de esos subdirectorios tengan archivos, les dejo mi codigo:

```
Private Sub populate()
        Dim rootNode As TreeNode


        Dim info As New DirectoryInfo("\\ruta\rutas\NombreCarpeta")

        If info.Exists Then

            rootNode = New TreeNode(info.Name)

            rootNode.Tag = info

            getDirectory(info.GetDirectories(), rootNode)

            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode)

        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub getDirectory(ByVal subDirs() As DirectoryInfo, ByVal nodeToAddTo As TreeNode)
        Dim aNode As TreeNode
        Dim subSubDirs() As DirectoryInfo
        Dim subDir As DirectoryInfo

        Dim ArchivoS() As FileInfo

        For Each subDir In subDirs

            aNode = New TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0)

            subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories()
            ''agregado..

            ArchivoS = subDir.GetFiles()
            For Each archivo As FileInfo In ArchivoS
                Dim aNode2 As TreeNode = New TreeNode(archivo.Name, 0, 0)
                nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode2)
            Next

            If subSubDirs.Length <> 0 Then

                getDirectory(subSubDirs, aNode)

            End If

            nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode)

        Next subDir

    End Sub
```

Lo que esta marcado con flechas rojas son subcarpetas y dentro de esas subcarpetas estan los pdf marcados con flechas azul, pero como ven me muestra todos en la misma lista y no es lo que busco, busco mostrar las subcarpetas y su contenido dentro de ellas, y que salgan asi como el nodo principal que se pueden expandir.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Hay aspectos en tu codigo, que no se corresponden con la logica de lo que deseas logar, te adjunto a continuación el código que creo te puede ayudar.

```
Private Sub populate()
        Dim rootNode As TreeNode
        Dim info As New DirectoryInfo("\\ruta\rutas\NombreCarpeta")
        If info.Exists Then
            rootNode = New TreeNode(info.Name)
            rootNode.Tag = info
            getDirectory(info.GetDirectories(), rootNode)
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode)
        End If
    End Sub
                                                    
    Private Sub getDirectory(ByVal subDirs() As DirectoryInfo, ByVal nodeToAddTo As TreeNode)
        Dim aNode As TreeNode
        Dim subSubDirs() As DirectoryInfo
        Dim subDir As DirectoryInfo
        Dim ArchivoS() As FileInfo
        For Each subDir In subDirs
          ''Creamos el nodo hijo
            aNode = New TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0)
           ''Agregamos el nodo hijo correspondiente al Suddirectorio
            nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode)
         ''Agregamos nodos hijos si son arcchivos
            For Each archivo As FileInfo In ArchivoS = subDir.GetFiles()
                Dim aNode2 As TreeNode = New TreeNode(archivo.Name, 0, 0)
                aNode.Nodes.Add(aNode2)
            Next
           ''Buscamos los SudDirectorios .
           subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories()

            If subSubDirs.Length > 0 Then
                ''Realizamos la llamada recursiva al metodo getDirectory
                getDirectory(subSubDirs, aNode)
            End If
        Next subDir
    End Sub
```

Comment: como comentaste era mas de logica el problema, hice algunas correcciones a tu respuesta y funciona como espere. Saludos.

Comment: @Manny. Me complace que te haya servido de algo mi respuesta, aún cuando hayas tenido que hacerle correcciones, todo es perfectible en este mundo. Te agradeceria que si la respuesta te resultó util, marcaras la respuesta como aceptada. Y en cualquier caso, gracias por tu comentario.